# java pdf generation in ITEXT

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to create a pdf file using Itext , here is the code

```
public static String generatePdfReport(){
try {       

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("SimplePDFTableColspan.pdf"));
    document.open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("column span 2"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);

    table.addCell("1");
    table.addCell("2");

    table.addCell("3");
    table.addCell("4");

    table.addCell("5");
    table.addCell("6");     

    document.add(table);        
    document.close();
    return document.toString();

    } catch (Exception exe) {
        exe.printStackTrace();
                         }
 }
```

The problem the return type of the method is String but in Itext i am getting a document, so i am getting SAX exception:

> Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: The exception probably has nothing to do with the code you gave us, which doesn't do any XML/SAX processing. Show us the exception stack trace, and the part of the code which actually throws the exception (which is at the top of the stack trace)

Comment: PDF is a binary format, that happens to contain some human-readable strings.  Its not an XML schema, its not text.  Its PDF.  What exactly did you want from `document.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that this is a static method with an empty paramter list.  If that's the case, please correct your code.

Do you think it's wise to have an empty catch block?  Your code will swallow any exception that's thrown and you won't be the wiser.  Print the stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

The method toString() of class Document seems to be inherited from class Object, and probably won't do what you intend (it certainly won't export the document as an XML String...).

Instead of a FileOutputStream, you could use a ByteArrayOutputStream, and then perform a string conversion on this data.

```
Document document = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
document.open();
...
document.close();
....
return output.toString();
```

Regards,
Guillaume

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()` certainly won't do what he wants either (it uses the platform default encoding to decode what is basically random binary data). In fact returning a `String` when he wants to return a PDF file isn't what he wants to do in the first place!

Comment: @Joachim. You're right. I basically thought that PDF was a text oriented file format, and that the bytearray would contains the content. Checking with a text editor removed this possibility. It imply that you're also right on the fact that getting PDF as a string is not a good idea. Regards